# ansible convert escaped json string to json

Tags: python, json, ansible, jmespath

I have an Ansible output that looks like this but have struggled to parse this to JSON without the escaped strings.

```
{
    "msg": [
        "{",
        "\t\"inprog\" : [",
        "\t\t{",
        "\t\t\t\"desc\" : \"conn174272\",",
        "\t\t\t\"threadId\" : \"139899377280768\",",
        "\t\t\t\"connectionId\" : 174272,",
        "\t\t\t\"client\" : \"127.0.0.1:43365\",",
        "\t\t\t\"active\" : true,",
        "\t\t\t\"opid\" : 35571992,",
        "\t\t\t\"secs_running\" : 0,",
        "\t\t\t\"microsecs_running\" : NumberLong(16),",
        "\t\t\t\"op\" : \"command\",",
        "\t\t\t\"ns\" : \"admin.$cmd\",",
        "\t\t\t\"query\" : {",
        "\t\t\t\t\"currentOp\" : 1",
        "\t\t\t},",
        "\t\t\t\"numYields\" : 0,",
        "\t\t\t\"locks\" : {",
        "\t\t\t\t",
        "\t\t\t},",
        "\t\t\t\"waitingForLock\" : false,",
        "\t\t\t\"lockStats\" : {",
        "\t\t\t\t",
        "\t\t\t}",
        "\t\t}",
        "\t],",
        "\t\"ok\" : 1",
        "}"
    ]
}
```

ideally the output should resemble something like:

```
{
    "inprog": [
        {
            "desc": "conn5404",
            "threadId": "139922277680896",
            "connectionId": 5404,
            "client": "127.0.0.1:50726",
            "active": true,
            "opid": 225819,
            "secs_running": 0,
            "microsecs_running": NumberLong(20),
            "op": "command",
            "ns": "admin.$cmd",
            "query": {
                "currentOp": 1
            },
            "numYields": 0,
            "locks": {
            },
            "waitingForLock": false,
            "lockStats": {
            }
        }]
}
```

I've tried JMESPath and [Ansible filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data) but no luck. any tips will be helpful. Latest attempt was

```
- name: get ops
  shell:
    cmd: mongo --eval  "db.currentOp()"
  register: currentOp

- debug:
    msg: "{{ currentOp.stdout_lines[2:] | to_json }}"
```

which resulted in:

```
{
    "msg": "[\"{\", \"\\t\\\"inprog\\\" : [\", \"\\t\\t{\", \"\\t\\t\\t\\\"desc\\\" : \\\"conn174318\\\",\", \"\\t\\t\\t\\\"threadId\\\" : \\\"139899381491456\\\",\", \"\\t\\t\\t\\\"connectionId\\\" : 174318,\", \"\\t\\t\\t\\\"client\\\" : \\\"127.0.0.1:43374\\\",\", \"\\t\\t\\t\\\"active\\\" : true,\", \"\\t\\t\\t\\\"opid\\\" : 35579590,\", \"\\t\\t\\t\\\"secs_running\\\" : 0,\", \"\\t\\t\\t\\\"microsecs_running\\\" : NumberLong(15),\", \"\\t\\t\\t\\\"op\\\" : \\\"command\\\",\", \"\\t\\t\\t\\\"ns\\\" : \\\"admin.$cmd\\\",\", \"\\t\\t\\t\\\"query\\\" : {\", \"\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"currentOp\\\" : 1\", \"\\t\\t\\t},\", \"\\t\\t\\t\\\"numYields\\\" : 0,\", \"\\t\\t\\t\\\"locks\\\" : {\", \"\\t\\t\\t\\t\", \"\\t\\t\\t},\", \"\\t\\t\\t\\\"waitingForLock\\\" : false,\", \"\\t\\t\\t\\\"lockStats\\\" : {\", \"\\t\\t\\t\\t\", \"\\t\\t\\t}\", \"\\t\\t}\", \"\\t],\", \"\\t\\\"ok\\\" : 1\", \"}\"]"
}
```

the idea is to create a new array of json from the output. for example, `[{"secs_running": 123, "opid": 1232342}]`

Comment: In general, a good question also shows what you tried and exactly how it failed (whether that's an error or incorrect output).

Comment: updated question with latest attempt using ansible filter `to_json`

Comment: You might try `join()`ing the lines first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved it with `mongo --quiet --eval "print(JSON.stringify(db.currentOp()))"` since Mongo shell is a Javascript interactive shell `JSON.stringify` did the magic to return JSON response

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of strings, one per line.

In shell, pipe to jq:

```sh
jq -r '.msg[]'
```

...or you can feed your data as stdin to the following Python:

```py
import sys, json
for line in json.load(sys.stdin).msg:
  print(line)
```

Comment: thanks but this wouldn't work since the ansible play is run from a yml task file

Comment: Can you post part of the ansible file so we can see the source & intended destination of the data?

Comment: updated description with more tasks from the file. the destination will be a new JSON created from the output

Comment: If your initial question was correctly answered as-asked, it's generally more appropriate to open a new question if it wasn't asked with a broad enough scope to address your real problem, rather than morphing that prior question into a new form.